# How can I extend CanvasRenderer in Three.js for a custom material?

Tags: three.js

What's the best way to extend CanvasRenderer in Three.js for a custom material?

I've got a ShaderMaterial for customized dashed lines in WebGL, but I need CanvasRenderer support as well. I figure I could create a custom material that extends the Material class. But I'm sure I'll have to extend Canvas Renderer in some way. How should I go about that? Copy and paste, creating a new class entirely?

Here is a jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/VyP29/1/) `.` of what I want to do, but in WebGL. I need the lines to stay a consistent length so it will probably have to be implemented by expanding a single line to multiple lines and gaps (for the CanvasRenderer).

Comment: `CanvasRenderer` does support `LineDashedMaterial`: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/canvas_lines_dashed.html But it doesn't match the result in `WebGLRenderer` yet... However, I suspect you need the dashes spacing to be more custom...?

Comment: Yes. It needs to take a pattern such as [0.5, -0.5, 0.25, -0.25], with variable length. Did the jsfiddle work for you? Someone else told me the result was blank, but works fine for me.

Comment: So I can see context2d does support that pattern natively. But WebGL then would need your implementation. Maybe we could change `LineDashedMaterial` implementation? Care to create an issue on github about it?

Comment: Sure thing. It's a slight possibility I'll need some other custom functionality to support dots in the pattern (represented as a 0 value), but none-the-less I will create an issue. I suppose Canvas Renderer isn't built for extensibility then?

Comment: Yeah, at the moment I wouldn't know how `CanvasRenderer` could handle such extensibility...